# How to find the specific run for a logic app failure alert?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring

When an alert is sent to ICM or Azure Monitor it sends the time of creation, among other somewhat useless information. Since alerts can be delayed by 5 minutes or so, creationTime for the alert will be off and this causes issues when a Logic App runs more than once within a 5-minute span.

Is there a way to see which run triggered the alert? Is there was a way to attach the associated runId and send it with the alert payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get run id of logic app with payload using compose action and dynamic expressions. I have reproduced issue from my side.

Below are steps I followed.

1. Created an alert and configured action group in conditions tab.
2. Created logic app to send mail with payload as shown below,

[image]

3. In Initialize variable, taking the payload in a variable.

[image]

4. In compose action added runid with dynamic expressions as workflow().run.name

[image]

5. In send email action, outputs of compose action.

[image]

6. When condition satisfied logic app ran successfully, and mail sent successfully

[image]

Reference for workflow [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#workflow)